# Single, global, object instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, singleton, global-variables

I've been slowly churning through my first iPhone app, outside of learning within the context of a book. What I would like to have is a single, global variable that tracks whether or not there is a person logged into the application. In the past with C++, what I've done is declared a variable in my "main" function file and then re-declared it in my other files as ***extern***. I've tried this with Objective-C, but I'm running into memory management issues when debugging with Leaks. Here is the code I'm trying to use.

***main*** file

```
#import "clsPerson.h"

clsPerson *LoggedInPerson = nil;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//...main code...
}
```

**[App]_Prefix.pch*** - Prefix file

```
...
#import "clsPerson.h"
extern clsPerson *LoggedInPerson;
...
```

**Login code** - Login View Controller (Modal popup on top of Root)

I should mention here also, that it currently checks to see if the variable is ***nil***. If it is, then it forces you to login. In order to use nil, I believe I have to alloc and dealloc rather than reusing the same memory address?

```
...
LoggedInPerson = [[clsPerson alloc] initWithJSON:(NSDictionary*)Network.JsonValues];
[LoggedInPerson retain]; //I don't really know if this is needed?

//Save this person into the default settings for next time
[LoggedInPerson saveUserInfo];
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
...
```

**Logout code** - Root View Controller

```
...
- (void)btnLogoutTapped {
    [LoggedInPerson dealloc]; //There is only one object, so I tried to force it to dealloc fully
    LoggedInPerson = nil;
    [clsPerson ClearUserInfo];
    ...
}
...
```

This seems to work fine and doesn't produce any errors, but watching the app with Leaks shows that my allocation statement is leaking memory somewhere. It typically happens if I logout, force a "low memory warning", and then login again. Are there any glaring problems here? I'm still getting my grips around memory management, but I think I'm pretty close. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you don't need to retain the object if you've just allocated it. The retain count will already be +1.

But the other issue is you should be **releasing** it when the user logs out, not deallocating it. You should never call dealloc directly.

Comment: I've tried it like that and still had it telling me there was memory leaks. Is it valid to assign and alloc in the same line? When it goes out-of-scope in terms of the function it was assigned in (even though I have a global reference) does Leaks throw a false positive on a memory leak? I'm a bit confused if I'm even doing anything wrong here, or if this is a leak I should be straining myself over. I'd love to be leak free, but I almost don't see it happening.

Comment: hard to say anything definitive, without obviously seeing what Leaks is telling you. Leaks isn't perfect, but in my experience it handles globals like this fine (many people do singletons as a global very similar to this). And yes, alloc/init and assign in one line is normal.

Comment: Look for a case where you might be assigning a new clsPerson* when there actually was a previous one (non-nil)